# How to make JUnit test with Mockito on API requests

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have `CurrencyService` class:

```
public class CurrencyService {

    public double exchange(String CurrencyFrom, String CurrencyTo, double amount) {
        String baseUrl = "https://api.apilayer.com/currency_data/";
        String apiKey = "TMrs25g3tBZe2qvKJNgMqcQOMNAQe1Md";
        String urlStr = baseUrl + "convert?amount=" + amount + "&from=" + CurrencyFrom + "&to=" + CurrencyTo + "&apikey=" + apiKey;
        //System.out.println(urlStr);

        //http request
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(urlStr)).build();
        String responseBody = client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                .join();

        double convertedValue = parseJSON(responseBody);

        return convertedValue;
    }

    public double parseJSON(String responseBody) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(responseBody, JsonObject.class);

        if (jsonObject != null && jsonObject.has("result")) {
            return jsonObject.get("result").getAsDouble();
        } else {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }

}
```

Now I need to write JUnit tests with Mockito. But how to do it without using internet connection?

I tried something like this but it not looks good :( ...

```
private CurrencyService currencyService;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        currencyService = Mockito.mock(CurrencyService.class);
    }


    @Test
    public void testExchange() {
        String currencyFrom = "USD";
        String currencyTo = "EUR";
        double amount = 100.0;
        double expectedValue = 49.34;

        Mockito.when(currencyService.exchange(currencyFrom, currencyTo, amount)).thenReturn(49.34);


        double convertedValue = currencyService.exchange(currencyFrom, currencyTo, amount);

        assertEquals(expectedValue, convertedValue, 0.001);
    }
```

It doesn't make sense when I first use Mockito.when and then check if it works good..

Comment: You are correct in that the test doesn't really check anything this way. Mockito works by introducing a "dumb" version of the class that you mock, and its use case is to mock secondary classes within the class that you test. But your class doesn't have secondary classes, so you don't really have anything to mock. However, if you created the httpClient outside of the class and instead retrieve it through a constructor, mockito could mock the HttpClient, allowing you to ensure a consequent response when calling client.sendAsync().